# Django's runserver hangs when inline added. 1.8 version

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

The following code makes django's dev server hanging. Browser just infinitely waits for page to load.

```
class PriceTagInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = PriceTag


class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PriceTagInline]


admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

However,

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)
```

works perfectly. No logs in runserver console. Please, advise. Django 1.8, python 3.4

Comment: Show the `PriceTag` model, please.

Comment: here it is
    class PriceTag(models.Model):
        image = models.ForeignKey(Article2Image, related_name='price_tags')
        product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
        x = models.IntegerField()
        y = models.IntegerField()

Comment: anyways, sounds like I figured the issue. As @catavaran suggested, the problem was in the mode. 'Article2Image' table had tons of records and inline was not able to render the 3 choice fields for each inline form. The solution was to replace it with autocomple_light. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the issue. The problem was in the model 'Article2Image'. The table had tons of records and inline was not able to render the 3 choice fields for each inline form. The solution was to replace it with autocomple_light.